# Sum of calculated field returns wrong result in MS Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate-functions

I have these 2 tables:

**Table1**:

```
CustomerID Area     Type                   Revenue
1          Europe   Institutional Clients   10
2          Asia     Institutional Clients   10
3          USA      Institutional Clients   10
```

**Table2**:

```
Report Country       Type                   Rate
DK                 Institutional Clients    2
SE                 Institutional Clients    2
FI                 Institutional Clients    2
```

I want to make a query that joins the two tables and make a calculated field (Revenue*Rate). But when I use the MS Access query designer the sum of calculated field returns the wrong result.

**Query version1**:
This query returns 20 per customer (which is correct) and 60 in total, but the fields are not grouped into 1 row. (if I remove the fields CustomerID and Area I get 1 row, but result says 20?! Se version1B below)

```
SELECT t_Customer.CustomerID, t_Customer.Area, t_Customer.Type, [Revenue]*[Rate] AS CalculatedField
FROM t_Customer INNER JOIN t_Rate ON t_Customer.Type = t_Rate.Type
GROUP BY t_Customer.CustomerID, t_Customer.Area, t_Customer.Type, [Revenue]*[Rate];
```

Returns:

```
CustomerID   Area   Type                  CalculatedField
1            Europe Institutional Clients   20
2            Asia   Institutional Clients   20
3            USA    Institutional Clients   20
```

**Query version1B**:  I remove the fields CustomerID and Area.

```
SELECT t_Customer.Type, ([Revenue]*[Rate]) AS CalculatedField
FROM t_Customer INNER JOIN t_Rate ON t_Customer.Type = t_Rate.Type
GROUP BY t_Customer.Type, ([Revenue]*[Rate]);
```

Returns:

```
Type                 CalculatedField
Institutional Clients   20
```

**Query version2**:
Here I add SUM of the Calculated field.
This query returns 180 (which is wrong).

```
SELECT t_Customer.Type, Sum(([Revenue]*[Rate])) AS CalculatedField
FROM t_Customer INNER JOIN t_Rate ON t_Customer.Type = t_Rate.Type
GROUP BY t_Customer.Type;
```

Returns:

```
Type                   CalculatedField
Institutional Clients   180
```

Is there a way to use the MS Access query designer to display the correct Sum of the calculated field, so I can have only 1 query for this purpose?

I know I could just make a new query on top of **Query version1** that makes the correct sum. But I would like to avoid having 2 queries for this purpose.

Comment: How do you know what rate is for which customer? If you go by the `Type` column, all 3 rates are joined with every row in the Customer table, therefor you get 180 (3*60)

Comment: Is there a third table describing the relationship between ReportCountry and Area? That is the key to the query you're trying to write

Comment: I don't know the rate for each customer. I agree that it's poor table design of table2. But just think of table2 as some kind of mastertable that could hold even more static data not tied to the single customer, but tied to Type or ReportCountry.

Comment: There is no third table. So my problem is having build the tables the way they are, how to make a correct calculated sum under those conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t_Customer.CustomerID,
       t_Customer.Area, 
       t_Customer.Type, 
       [Revenue] * [Rate] AS CalculatedField
  FROM t_Customer 
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Type, Rate 
         FROM t_rate) t_rate ON t_Customer.Type = t_Rate.Type
```

If you want it all one row then:

```
  SELECT t_Customer.Type, 
         SUM([Revenue] * [Rate]) AS CalculatedField
    FROM t_Customer 
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Type, Rate 
            FROM t_rate) t_rate ON t_Customer.Type = t_Rate.Type
GROUP BY t_Customer.Type
```

Returns:

```
Type                    CalculatedField
Institutional Clients   60
```

Note that this change cannot be made with Access Query Designer (in Design Mode) you have to switch to SQL View.

Also note that the SELECT DISTINCT part can be typed both within parentheses like this

```
(SELECT DISTINCT Type,Rate FROM t_rate)
```

but Access will convert it to

```
[SELECT DISTINCT Type,Rate FROM t_rate].
```

when you save and edit the query again.
It produces the same result though. So it works just fine.

Comment: The join is made on the Type field having the value "Institutional Clients". And because of 3 repetitive values of "Institutional Clients" in table2, each row in table1 is joined 3 times, making the result 3 times to big. Unless I use 2 queries, one for joining, and one for making the sum.

Comment: Use Subquery with DISTINCT values of rate per type which you will join with your primary table. Group by seems not needed right now.

Comment: Is there an easy way to do that using the Access Query Designer, and still having only 1 query?

Comment: @MOLAP You can paste @niktrs answer into an Access query (SQL mode). it's perfectly fine in Access

Comment: Create a view with the subquey and then join the main table with the view

Comment: @hawbsl Ok thanks. The syntax is a little special with the distinct part, since Access is adding a dot (.) after the distinct sentence which it puts in [] This is what Access converts the sql to: `SELECT t_Customer.Type, Sum([Revenue]*[Rate]) AS CalculatedField FROM t_Customer INNER JOIN [SELECT DISTINCT Type,Rate FROM t_rate]. AS t_rate ON t_Customer.Type = t_rate.Type GROUP BY t_Customer.Type;`